# htaccess breaks assets paths

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to find a way of including a htaccess rewrite to redirect anyone visiting http://site.com to http://www.site.com.

I've tried the following...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...but this also broke the paths to all of my assets (in various folders, which bizarrely can not be renamed) - adding a "www" where there shouldn't be one.

How can I get around this issue?

**Solution:**

Obvious now that I think of it - create another htaccess in the assets folder like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.co.uk/assets/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.co.uk/assets/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `adding a "www" where there shouldn't be one.` And where would that be? Could you give an example what goes wrong?

Comment: No chance to test now, but to me it looks like you're rewriting www.site.co.uk to itself, shouldn't it just be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.co.uk [NC]`?

Comment: Chrome's console, for example, cannot load any js files (404) - the path it says it can't access includes "www", whereas the actual filepath does not.

Comment: Re: your second comment - no, the syntax is correct.

Comment: No idea how `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.co.uk/assets/ [NC]` is working because request URI paths aren't part of the HTTP `Host:` header

Comment: Interesting point - I'm an apache noob tbh. It could have been a cname entry taking a while to come into effect - perhaps writing an htaccess to each directory initiated some kind of refresh/reset. Helluva coincidence,

Comment: I don't think the syntax is correct: `site.com` and `www.site.com` are both accepted but the last one generates a loop.